# Select from a table, add a parameter to the result and return it from a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function that returns the result of a select based on a parameter being passed to it. I would like to join the parameter to the returned result of the function. Here's an example:

```
create or replace function somefunc(param varchar)
returns table(fielda varchar, fieldb int, param varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
        return query
    select
    fielda varchar,
    fieldb int,
    param varchar -- HOW DO I SELECT IT?
    from  
        sometable
    join
        othertable on id = other_id
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the parameter correctly

I created a fake `sometable` table and inserted two rows with

```
create table sometable(fielda varchar, fieldb int);
insert into sometable values('a',1);
insert into sometable values('b',2);
```

Then specified the `somefunc` function with

```
create or replace function somefunc(param_in varchar)
returns table(fielda varchar, fieldb int, param varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
        return query
    select
    sometable.fielda,
    sometable.fieldb,
    param_in 
    from sometable;
end;
$$
```

Check out the `param_in` input parameter not in contrast with the `param` field in the table. I removed the join with the `othertable` but that can also be added.

Comment: Note: you dont need plpgsql for this, it can be done in plan SQL.